# Check in Subfolder for PHP Files with nginx

Tags: nginx

Here is what I'm trying to do: When a URI is loaded, I want nginx to first check the `/legacy/` folder to see if that exact path exists, and if not, then to send that to Laravel.

Laravel is my root folder. I have moved my Legacy files to a the legacy folder inside my root Laravel app.

Here is what I have so far, but unfortunately with this all of my requests are returning File not found.

A few notes about my setup: I have multiple versions of PHP installed, and I know that `fastcgi_pass php74` works in all setups. What I'm struggling with is getting the `try_files` working so it knows where to look for the files, and send them to PHP-FPM.

I want the URLs to stay the same, so http://example.com/some/legacy/app.php will load from `../document/root/legacy/some/legacy/app.php` instead of being sent to Laravel.

```
...snipped...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files /legacy/$uri @regularphp;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass php74;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/legacy/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

    location @regularphp {
        fastcgi_pass php74;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Try: `try_files /legacy$uri $uri =404;` and use `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Comment: @RichardSmith That fixed it so the Laravel app loads correctly. Still getting File not found for files inside the legacy folder, however

Comment: The last three `location` blocks should probably be one `location` block. Try: `location ~ \.php$ { try_files /legacy$uri $uri =404; fastcgi_pass php74; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name; ... }`

Comment: Holy crap that worked. Thank you! I have been fighting with this literally all day long!

Comment: The other thing I had to do was stop being dumb and move my files out of the ROOT Laravel folder, and put them inside the PUBLIC folder so they were at the NGINX ROOT.